# I have project created by laravel 8 ,and i use JWT for my API ,now i can't install pusher because of JWT version

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, jwt, pusher, laravel-8

Someone can help me to fix this conflict

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- tymon/jwt-auth is locked to version 1.0.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
- tymon/jwt-auth 1.0.2 requires php ^5.5.9|^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.1) does not satisfy that requirement.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

Comment: You can use `composer require tymon/jwt-auth --ignore-platform-reqs` to quiclky fix that

Comment: Thank you sir. i try composer require pusher/pusher-php-server  tymon/jwt-auth --ignore-platform-reqs   it's worked

Answer (score 0):

If using Larvel `Version 8` use `composer require -w tymon/jwt-auth --ignore-platform-reqs`.

Answer (score 0):

### Just run

`composer update`

##### Or

`composer require tymon/jwt-auth`

Answer (score 0):

it's work for me

```
composer require {{**Your package name**}} --ignore-platform-reqs
```